# How to draw a graphicLines in InDesign using CEP / ExtendScript?

Tags: draw, adobe-indesign, extendscript, adobe-extension

I saw that there was a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34832625/drawing-a-line-in-indesign-cs5-5-using-extendscript) but my problem is not the same :

This is how I create my graphicLines :

```js
var myArr = [
   [x1, y1],
   [x2, y2],
   ...
]
// Get the active document
var doc = app.activeDocument;

// Get item from the page
var page = doc.pages.item(0);

var line = page.graphicLines.add();
line.paths.item(0).entirePath = myArr;
```

I should have this (the line circled in blue) :

[image]

But I get this (the rectangle circled in blue) :

[image]

This rectangle appears when I click on the focus, otherwise it is nonexistent.
[image]

The rectangle seems to be the size of the line and is well positioned but I did not get the line I wanted. What did I forget ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add this line at the end of your snippet:

```
line.strokeWeight = 1;
```